# Prove complex logarithm problem involving Euler Mascheroni constant

Tags: logarithms, laplace-transform, euler-mascheroni-constant

I want to prove/disprove the following equation:
$$\text{Log}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}} = -\frac12 \ln\left(\frac{1}{z^2}+1\right)-\ln\lvert z\rvert - \gamma$$

Which $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni constant.

This problem arise when my textbook said
$$\mathcal{L} \Bigg\{\frac{\cos(t)}{t}\Bigg\} = \text{Log}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right)\tag{1}$$
But, Wolfram gave me
$$\mathcal{L} \Bigg\{\frac{\cos(t)}{t}\Bigg\} = -\frac12 \ln\left(\frac{1}{s^2}+1\right)-\ln\lvert z\rvert - \gamma\tag{2}$$

My attempt:
Here, my working start is deal with my laplace transform:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} \Bigg\{\frac{\cos(t)}{t}\Bigg\} &= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}\cos(t)}{t}\,\Bbb dt\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-st}\left(e^{it}+e^{-it}\right)}{2t}\,\Bbb dt\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{t(s-i)}}{2t}\,\Bbb dt + \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t(s+i)}}{2t}\,\Bbb dt  
\end{align}$$

I'm stuck there. If i continue, maybe i would get some exponential integral function. But how to produce equation $(1)$ or $(2)$??

I need a help. Thanks!

P.S. haven't tried to use $\text{Log}(z) = \ln|z| + i\text{Arg}(z)$ since i don't know what $\text{Arg}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}\right)$ is.
And btw, i'm not sure Wolfram use $\log$ as $\text{Log}$ or $\ln$.
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Umm... what is ${\cal L}_t$?

Comment: A laplace transform w.r.t variable t?

Comment: According to the definition of [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) they are **both** wrong because the integral does not exist due to behavior at $\,t=0.$ Your definition of Laplace transform is wrong because it should be $dt$ and not $ds$.

Comment: @Somos edited. Thanks.

Comment: Branches of the logarithm differ by $2\pi n i$, the first identity cannot be correct. The issue is how the LT of $\cos(t)/t$ is defined, since the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-s t} \cos(t)/t \, dt$ doesn't exist. In terms of distributions,
$$\mathcal L[\operatorname {Ci}](s) =
-\frac {\ln(s^2 + 1)} {2 s}, \\
\operatorname {Ci}'(t) =
t_+^{-1} \cos t + \gamma \delta(t), \\
\mathcal L[\operatorname {Ci}'](s) =
s \mathcal L[\operatorname {Ci}](s)$$
($\operatorname {Ci}$ is a regular distribution supported on $[0, \infty)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way the Laplace transform can be derived:

$$
\begin{align}
f(t) &= cos(t)/t \\
t f(t) &= cos(t) \\
\mathcal{L} \Bigg\{t f(t)\Bigg\} &= \mathcal{L} \Bigg\{ cos(t) \Bigg\} \\
-\frac{d}{ds} \mathcal{L} \Bigg\{ f(t)\Bigg\} &= \frac {s}{s^2 + 1} \\
\mathcal{L} \Bigg\{ f(t)\Bigg\} &= - \int \frac {s}{s^2 + 1} ds \\
u &= s^2 + 1 \\
\mathcal{L} \Bigg\{ f(t)\Bigg\} &= - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac {1}{u} du \\
 &= - \frac{1}{2} ln(u) + C \\
 &= - \frac{1}{2} ln(s^2 + 1) + C \\
 &= ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}}) + C
\end{align}
$$

IVT/FVT to find the value of the integration constant.

You'll notice that both of your forms are very close to each other:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} ln (\frac{1}{s^2}+1) - ln(s) \\
-\frac{1}{2} ln (\frac{s^2 + 1}{s^2}) - ln(s) \\
\frac{1}{2} ln (\frac{s^2}{s^2+1}) - ln (s) \\
ln (\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}) - ln(s) \\
ln (\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}})
$$

So the question comes down to the integration constant $-\gamma$