# Inverse Laplace transform of $\ln(s^2 +1)$ using countour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $\ln\left(s^{2}+1\right)$ using contour integration, Which could be found by:

$$ \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\ln\left(s^{2}+1\right)e^{st}ds $$

As the function has two branch points, at $s = \pm i$, I considered the contour:

[image: 1]

Whereat the end I get that the integral of the arc vanishes, and the integrals over the negative real part of the contour cancel each other out. I'm just left with the integrals over the branch points, which I'm going to call $ \alpha_{1} $ and $ \alpha_{2} $.

For $ \alpha_{1} $ I get $ \int_{0}^{i}\left[\ln\left(s^{2}+1\right)+\frac{5i\pi}{2}\right]e^{st}ds + \int_{i}^{0}\left[\ln\left(s^{2}+1\right)+\frac{i\pi}{2}\right]e^{st}ds $ which is equal to $ 2i\pi\int_{0}^{i}e^{st}ds $

For $ \alpha_{2} $ I get $ \int_{0}^{-i}\left[\ln\left(s^{2}+1\right)-\frac{i\pi}{2}\right]e^{st}ds + \int_{-i}^{0}\left[\ln\left(s^{2}+1\right)+\frac{3i\pi}{2}\right]e^{st}ds $ which is equal to $ -2i\pi\int_{0}^{-i}e^{st}ds $

In my calculations, the semi-circle integrals over +i and -i are 0, so at the end my final answer would be $ \int_{\alpha_{1}}^{ }+\int_{\alpha_{2}}^{ } $, and I get $ -\frac{2i\pi}{t}\left(e^{it}-e^{-it}\right) $. As the final answer for the inverse Laplace I get $ \frac{-2i}{t}\sin\left(t\right) $, which is not the correct answer. My question is what am I missing in the countour? Maybe I set up the arguments of $ \ln\left(s^{2}+1\right) $ wrong, or maybe the integrals over the real part does not cancel out, any help or hint would be welcome, thank you!

The correct answer is $ \frac{2\cos\left(t\right)}{t} $

Comment: You may want to check your argument that the integral over the arc vanishes - the arc partially lives in the right half plane and dominated convergence would not apply

Comment: Something's fishy here. The Laplace transform of $\frac{2\cos t}{t}$ cannot be $\log(s^2+1)$, since for $s\to 0^+$ the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\cos t}{t}e^{-st}\,dt$ diverges due to the pole at the origin.

Comment: And the Laplace transform of $2\frac{1-\cos t}{t}$ is not $\log(1+s^2)$ but $\log(1+s^{-2})$.

Comment: The Bromwich integral diverges, which can be shown by applying IBP and Dirichlet's test. In terms of distributions, whether or not $-2 \cos(t)/t$ is correct depends on how you define $1/t$. If $t_+^{-1}$ is defined as the distributional derivative of $(\ln t)_+$, then $\mathcal L^{-1}[s \mapsto \ln(s^2 + 1)](t)$ will give $-2 t_+^{-1} \cos t$ [plus a delta function term](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3985686).

Comment: I'm curious where you found or saw "the correct answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something's definitely wrong in the question. Assume that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\log(1+s^2) = f(x)$. Then

$$ (\mathcal{L}f)(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) e^{-sx}  dx = \log(s^2+1) $$

so by considering the limit as $s\to 0^+$ we have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) dx = 0$, no particular concern. The actual concern comes from the fact that $\log(s^2+1)$ is increasing and diverges as $s\to +\infty$, while *usually* $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) e^{-sx} dx$ converges to $0$. By differentiating with respect to $s$ we have

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left( x f(x) \right) e^{-sx} = -\frac{2s}{s^2+1} $$

so the only chance is $x f(x) = -2\cos(x)$, or $f(x)=-2\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$. However this function has a simple pole at the origin, hence $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) e^{-sx}\,dx $ *does not* converge for any $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\log(s^2+1)$ *is not* a Laplace transform.

---

There are several criteria for establishing that a function *is not* a Laplace transform, also depending on the chosen domain for $\mathcal{L}$. Even without considering the derivative as I did above, $\log(s^2+1)$ does not meet criterion (3) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44988/30521) (Paley-Wiener-type) - this is essentially the objection in the first comment.

Another simple criterion is that any measurable $f$ with a sub-exponential growth is such that $(\mathcal{L}f)(s)$ converges to zero as $s\to +\infty$. Additionally, if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is non-negative, its Laplace transform is log-convex. In particular the Laplace transform of a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ can be written as $e^{g_1(s)}-e^{g_2(s)}$ with $g_1,g_2$ being convex functions with the same limit as $s\to +\infty$.

Comment: It seems the closest one can get legitimately is [Gradshteyn & Ryzhik 3.951.3]:
\begin{equation}
\log(1 + s^2) = 2\int_0^\infty\, \frac{1 - e^{-st}}{t}\cos t\, dt.
\end{equation}